# Umbraco vs DotNetNuke with own template

Tags: html, umbraco, dotnetnuke

I would like to ask you to which one from this two systems i can easier implement my own template? I have ready template of my web page and i want to integrate it with one of this systems, my template contains some js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it easy, I prefer to use Umbraco, because DNN for now, it is powerful and complex solution.And it will take more time for integration.

If your website really really simple, most probably,  you can build website with Umbraco without any line of custom code c#.

Comment: So i have ready template with html and js, this web page exctly exist and i want to integrate this tamplate with some of this systems, and which one will allow me to do it easier. I don't know this systems quite well and in this time i don't know how it works, i pick my template from pc and share it with this system or i can do somethink more?

Comment: Of course it is much much more than "pick my template from pc and share it with this system" with both systems. IMHO Umbraco is easier for new people. But still, require work and efforts to build website

Comment: Can you tell me whats more need such template to start working with this system, some modules, sections and more?

Comment: You can check their documentation, because answer of this question is way-way bigger, than SO format.